# PostgreSQL update query with LAG() return "ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression"

Tags: postgresql

I have table in my PostgreSQL database like below example. It has an empty column which needed to filled by previous row value

```
ship_id|ship_class     |bow_number|name            |date_start_ops|previous_name|
-------|---------------|----------|----------------|--------------|-------------|
010    |Albatross Class|       010|Albatross       |1980-01-05    |             |
010    |Albatross Class|      909X|AP010           |1979-12-25    |             |
012    |Jaguar    Class|       010|Jaguar          |1978-11-05    |             |
012    |Jaguar    Class|     8091X|JX010           |1970-05-10    |             |
```

and it must filled like this:

```
ship_id|ship_class     |bow_number|name            |date_start_ops|previous_name|
-------|---------------|----------|----------------|--------------|-------------|
010    |Albatross Class|       010|Albatross       |1980-01-05    |AP101        |
010    |Albatross Class|      909X|AP010           |1979-12-25    |NULL         |
012    |Jaguar    Class|       010|Jaguar          |1978-11-05    |JX010        |
012    |Jaguar    Class|     8091X|JX010           |1970-05-10    |NULL         |
```

I try with this query:

```
update
    historic as a
set
    previous_name =
(select
    lag(name, 1) over (partition by ship_id, ship_class
order by
    date_start_ops)
from
    historic
)
where
    a.ship_id = ship_id
```

However it return error: "ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression" Any help are appreciated

Comment: You need to do a select on the name column and not include other, thats where your query says the sub query has more resultant columns than the ones you are trying to insert and also what are the results of the sub query alone? That can help you debug it better

Comment: What is the primary key of that table?

Comment: they don't have primary key on the table. I ony can rely on the id, ship_class and the date

Comment: There is no `id` column in your sample data. However a table without a primary key smells like a really bad design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a derived table that calculates all previous names once and join to that. As your table doesn't have a primary key (which is something you should really change), I used the internal "row identifier" from Postgres: ctid

```
update historic as a
  set previous_name = t.prev_name
from (
  select ctid as row_id, 
         lag(name, 1) over (partition by ship_id, ship_class 
                            order by date_start_ops) as prev_name
  from historic
) t
where a.ctid = t.row_id
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=006e4dad3e9e748c927e2fc93ac91383)